# Where are the majority of children on the Autism Spectrum?

Tags: autism

Our doctor suspects our 2 year old daughter has Autism so we have booked her in for an official diagnosis and we are madly reading everything we can on the net.

I can see under the DSM-IV Model that people fall under Aspergers, PDD-NOD, or classic Autism.

She had a delay in language (no dadda or mamma) so I know she would not meet the Aspergers. But motor skills seem fine, and her restrictive / repetitive play symptoms seem very mild.

What percentage of diagnosis fall into each category? Is Aspergers, PDD-NOS or Classic Autism the most common?

Comment: First, bravo to you for reading up on as much literature as you can for your child. But second, please do not try to self-diagnose.  Autism in particular is incredibly difficult to diagnose, so any signs you might be getting from her could be drastically wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What percentage of diagnosis fall into each category? Is Aspergers, PDD-NOS or Classic Autism the most common?

It's not an easy question to answer. Paper after paper disputes the validity of the manner of distinction of the subtypes, and differences between the DSM-IV and the DSM-V are significant, resulting in a reclassification of a large number of individuals into a different subtype. There is information out there, but it seems to be in flux, defying good statistical analysis. The most accepted and verifiable information seems to center around IQ. Many experts felt that autism is a *spectrum disorder* and Asperger's disorder was actually high-functioning autism, adding to the confusion.

Maybe someone else will have better luck answering this question.

From the American Psychiatric Association:

> Using DSM-IV, patients could be diagnosed with four separate disorders: autistic disorder, Asperger’s disorder, childhood disintegrative disorder, or the catch-all diagnosis of pervasive developmental disorder not otherwise specified. Researchers found that these separate diagnoses were not consistently applied across different clinics and treatment centers. Anyone diagnosed with one of the four pervasive developmental disorders (PDD) from DSM-IV should still meet the criteria for ASD in DSM-5 or another, more accurate DSM-5 diagnosis.

Early intervention is also *relatively* recent and its significant impact may make the classification more difficult.

> She had a delay in language... But motor skills seem fine, and her restrictive/repetitive play symptoms seem very mild.

That's important. Of children who end up with a diagnosis of autism,

> Studies have shown that parents of children with ASD notice a developmental problem before their child's first birthday. Concerns about vision and hearing were more often reported in the first year, and differences in social, communication, and fine motor skills were evident from 6 months of age.

Your videotapes are an important resource for you (and your clinicians) in the diagnosing of your daughter. A suggestion, if I may: watching them will help you as much as, maybe even more than reading on the internet. With a notebook in hand, you can document behaviors (or lack thereof) by dates of appearance. This is a way that you can actively help in your daughter's diagnosis and treatment program.

If you are looking for good websites on autism, I hope you have discovered the CDC page on [Autism Spectrum Disorder](http://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/autism/index.html) (it has a wealth of information) and [Autism Speaks](https://www.autismspeaks.org/family-services/tool-kits/100-day-kit) (more of a help after diagnosis).

Please know that questions are always welcome here.

<sub>[Autism Spectrum Disorder](http://www.dsm5.org/Documents/Autism%20Spectrum%20Disorder%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf)</sub>
<sub>[Examining the validity of autism spectrum disorder subtypes](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10803-008-0541-2#page-1)</sub>
<sub>[Outcome in High-Functioning Adults with Autism With and Without Early Language Delays: Implications for the Differentiation Between Autism and Asperger Syndrome](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022270118899#page-1)</sub>
<sub>[Top 10 Autism Websites Recommended by Parents](http://eden2.org/top-10-autism-websites-recommended-by-parents/)</sub>

Comment: Balanced and authoritative answer.

Comment: +1 For DSM-5. I was aware it reclassified ASD, which also impacts how some students receive special education. Any existing stats may not be "valid" once DSM-5 really takes off.